# Having issues in running SOAP API in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, soapui

Hi I'm try to execute a soap api script on jmeter but is returning 500. It's executing fine on SOAPUI

POST http://webservices.truckstop.com/v13/CACCI/Report.svc

Header manager: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Here's my body data:`soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v9="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v9" xmlns:web="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices" xmlns:web1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.CACCI">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v9:GetCompanySearchResults>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v9:searchRequest>
            <web:IntegrationId>313531</web:IntegrationId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <web:Password>uN648Msf</web:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <web:UserName>UNIQUESOFTWAREWS</web:UserName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <web1:Criteria>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web1:CompanyName>Fusion QA Carrier 1</web1:CompanyName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web1:DotNumber>3049485</web1:DotNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web1:McNumber>222222</web1:McNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web1:PhoneNumber>?</web1:PhoneNumber>
            </web1:Criteria>
         </v9:searchRequest>
      </v9:GetCompanySearchResults>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case you need to pass [SOAPAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssnws/bb3d9ea3-6f43-4c72-afc2-c873b304dcde) header as well

In general given the request works fine in SoapUI you should be able to record it in JMeter:

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Configure SoapUI to use JMeter as the proxy

   [image]
3. Start the request in SoapUI
4. JMeter should store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Alternatively you can use [soapui2yaml](https://gettaurus.org/docs/SoapUI/#soapui2yaml-Converting-Existing-SoapUI-Project-into-Taurus-YAML) tool which can convert your SoapUI script into [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) format which in its turn can be converted into a JMeter script if you run `bzt your_script.yaml -gui` command

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this:

```
   <!--Optional:-->
   <web1:PhoneNumber>?</web1:PhoneNumber>
```

The fact this is optional means you can just not specify this part in your query. However you send `?` value that might break server logic.